# Nesting a for loop in an if else statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

```
if [ ! -f ./* ]; then
  for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    echo $files
else
  echo Nothing here
fi
```

Returns

> syntax error near unexpected token `else'

New to this. Can anyone point me to what I did wrong?

Comment: I didn't down vote but there is one quote in your last echo.

Comment: Please do not change your question for an entirely different issue. You already had 3 answers explaining that you were missing "done". Your code actually doesn't make much sense. You want to cd into a directory if it doesn't exist? Why do you expect that reading the first line of the file will give you a filename?

Comment: @jordanm `New to this.` cut me some slack. nvr wrote shell scripts until yesterday cause my boss needs a script made on a server and the person who originally does it quit. I'm trying here =/

Comment: @Mechaflash writing something for production while learning a new language rarely has good results. After you are finished writing something that meets the specs, be prepared to throw it out and do it better using new knowledge you have picked up. My downvote was for changing the question, not the quality of your code. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: apologies. i'll revert the question back to its original form and start another post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `done`!

```
if [ ! -f ./* ]; then
  for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    echo $files
  done
else
  echo Nothing here
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get a syntax error is because you are not ending the loop with the "done" statement. You should be using a while loop, instead of a for loop in this case, as the for loop will break if any of the filenames contain spaces or newlines.

Also, the test command you have issued will also give a syntax error if the glob expands to multiple files.

```
$ [ ! -f ./* ]
bash: [: too many arguments
```

Here is a better way to check if the directory contains any files:

```
files=(./*) # populate an array with file or directory names
hasfile=false
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
   if [[ -f $file ]]; then
      hasfile=true
      break
   fi
done

if $hasfile; then
   while read -r file; do
      echo "$file"
   done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
fi
```

Also, you could simply replace the while loop with find -print if you have GNU find:

```
if $hasfile; then
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for "for" is

for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done

You are missing the "done"

Try

```
if [ ! -f ./* ]; then
  for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    echo $files
  done
else
  echo Nothing here
fi
```

BTW, did you mean echo with lowercase rather than ECHO?

Comment: `BTW, did you mean echo with lowercase rather than ECHO?` Yes I did. Thanks